# E-Mail requirement for connecting Azure DevOps to Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/connect-organization-to-azure-ad) explains how to connect an Azure DevOps organization to Azure AD and indicates that in order for users to keep their accesses, that they should have the same e-mail in both the account from DevOps and the account from AD.

Now, I have this doubt:

If I have a user on DevOps with a MS Account (MSA) `user@mydomain.com` and a user on Azure AD `user@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com` (with NO custom domain set up, I have my custom domain running on GoDaddy for now), does this mean that all the work items created on DevOps with `user@mydomain.com` will be left "orphan"? What would be the outcome of doing this? And what would happen if I add my custom domain AFTER connecting DevOps to AAD?

Comment: I have update my answer with some detailed explaination, please check it and share  your latest progress about any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this user's MS Account is the same one which be added in AAD, you don't need worry about the data.

Just connect organization with this AAD, and login with the previous MS Account(don't need to change anything) . The data still be obtain now.

> does this mean that all the work items created on DevOps with
>   user@mydomain.com will be left "orphan"?

This situation is only occurred on the MS account is not same with the account which be added in AAD. For this, if the user want to obtain and migrate the data from previous account. Need to contact our engineer [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=21), and we will help user migrate data from backend.

**Edit:** May caused by my not clearly expression let it confusion.

In fact, for add MSA into AAD, it's normal for all user account to do this operation. The only one affection is the account which should be login to Org after connect AAD to Org.

Here has two account: **a@outlook.com**(person account), **a@softcompany.com**(work account).

**Scene**: The account you used usually is **a@outlook.com**.

(1)If add this account into AAD, you don't need to do anything like migrate data after connect the org with AAD. Just still login with this account is ok.
(2)If add another account(**a@softcompany.com**) into AAD, you need to finish the **data migrate** and **identity transfer** operation after connect org with AAD, if you want to retain the data history.

**Note:** these two does not belong to any AAD before add them into the new AAD you want to AAD. Or it will be a more complex operation. If you meet this, feel free to share it here, I can share the detailed process with you about this complex situation.

Comment: "If this user's MS Account is the same one which be added in AAD, you don't need worry about the data" How would it be the same? How do I add an existing MSA account to AAD? So far, I only added a new user on AAD with user@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com. Would that be wrong?

Comment: @CesarD For example, if your personal MS Account is cesar@abc.com. While you add this user in AAD, just input this account address. And then, if added successfully, this account will be showed as cesar@abc.onmicrosoft.com in AAD. The “onmicrosoft.com” is the default symbol of domain by Microsoft. You can custom this domain later but no affection. It will not affect any data which stored under the account.

Comment: Oh, ok, so if right now I already created cesar@abc.onmicrosoft.com in AAD, should I delete it and create another account with cesar@abc.com and that would be it?

Comment: Now this is jogging my memory and I retried creating a user with "cesar@abc.com", but the username shows a validation error "'abc.com' is not a verified domain name in this directory".

Comment: @CesarD This means the domain of this account does not belong to the domain which register for this AAD. At this time, you need to add user with New Guest User option.

Comment: @CesarD Not create. Add this personal MS account into the AAD.

Comment: Right, I don't have the custom domain set up. So only options is to add my "cesar@abc.com" account as Guest User? Will I be able fully use my AAD with this?

Comment: @CesarD What’s the role of your account when you want to add other account into AAD but error occurred?

Comment: @CesarD In fact, if you worry about the permission of guest role, you can assign high access to this account.

Comment: The "not a verified domain on this directory" showed up when I was trying to CREATE a new user, not adding as guest. I understood later that you were pointing me to "Add as Guest", right? Is there any link to show and explain how to add MSA to domain and keep it as a member with Global Admin?

Comment: @CesarD Please refer to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/create-an-azure-active-directory-tenant#create-azure-active-directory-tenant-users

Comment: that link shows how to create new users in AAD, which I already managed to do, but what I would like to know is how to *add* an MSA as full member like you suggested (unless I misunderstood). From what I understand from your messages, having a whole new user wouldn't be the same as actually adding the MSA I already have to the AAD. Is that correct? And if I add an MSA, can it have full functionality and be treated as any other regular account created in the AAD? Thanks.

Comment: @CesarD Apologize for seemed that I let you misunderstand something. In fact, there’s no difference between have a whole new user and adding users in AAD. The affection is only the data which exist under the previous account and the login account. If you add a MSA, it’s same as the other regular account added in the AAD. Please refer to these two Microsoft blog : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/vs-subscriptions-and-linking-your-vsts-account-to-azuread/ and https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/vsts-will-no-longer-allow-creation-of-new-msa-users-with-custom-domain-names-backed-by-azuread/

Comment: Ok, I finally managed to complete the process. But it was easier once I set up the custom domain on our Azure AD. I still had to create a "migrator" user on AAD with GA role and add it to Azure DevOps and set as new owner for the process to complete. Also, this new user had to had access to the subscription I created with my own user before so DevOps could recognize the migrator user had an active subscription (and a non-free one). Those parts were result of side investigation I had to made :) thanks for your help @Merlin